# DJango-extensions autocomplete admin works on ids, not text

Tags: django, python-2.7

In the django admin, I'm trying to get my users to be able to search for name, autocomplete the field, and when selected the new model instance will store the id of the selected school, not the name.

I was able to get the fields to autocomplete on the unitid using django-extensions, but I want users to be able to search for an institution name and log the unitid.

My models:

```
models.py

class IPED(models.Model):
    unitid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    instnm = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class LISTING(models.Model):
    listid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    unitid = models.ForeignKey(IPED, to_field='unitid')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=600)

admin.py
from django_extensions.admin import ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin


class ListAdmin(ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin):
    list_display = ('listid','unitid',) 
    related_search_fields = {
        'unitid': ('unitid','instnm'), #when searching for a unitid, this plugin works. If I search for an instnm, it does not.
    }
```